# Calculate all peak-to-peak amplitudes in a signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have extracted all the peaks from a signal (maxima and minima) and have now 2 vectors containing their voltage values and two vectors containing their indexes.

I would like to calculate all the different peak-to-peak (minima to maxima and maxima to minima) values from this signal. Ultimately, this is to find the maximum peak-to-peak value of this signal. Because the signal is drifting, and I am not 'allowed' to high-pass filter it, this is the only way that I could think of finding this value. I am however scratching my head to implement it.

I would appreciate any help to build this code, or other ideas to achieve my goal. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is an example of my data points. `PosVol` is the voltages of the positive peaks and `NegVol` of the negative peaks. Respectively, `PosInd` and `NegInd` are the indexes.

```
PosVol = [ 0.0437   0.1680  0.2089  0.5719  0.9146  0.8306  0.8646 1.0000  0.6541  0.1628 -0.3038 -0.0990   0.3602   0.4707  0.2968  0.1793];
NegVol = [ 1.2838   1.6351  1.5026  1.1441  1.2331  1.2732  0.9188  0.1841  0.0412  0.6215  1.1444  1.0828  0.5687   0.2590   0.3917   0.5605];
PosInd = [ 1533  4057  6609 9038  11426 13831  16403  19009  21206 23609 27015   29758   32294  34789   37147   39642];
NegInd = [ 2304 4733 7283  9768  12291  14817   17397  20105   22899    25851  28218   30706  33317   36211  38628    41123];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that for getting all - let's say falling flanks - peak to peak values, you iterate over the postive indices and do:

```
PeakPeakFalling = zeros(1,size(PosInd,2));
for ii=1:size(PosInd,2)
    neg_index = find(NegInd(1,:)>PosInd(1,ii),1);
    PeakPeakFalling(1,ii)=PosVol(1,ii)+NegVol(1,neg_index);
end
```

This finds the next index of the following minimum and with that calculates the difference in value.

In the same way you could also build the `PeakPeakRising` vector and then just find the maximum of all peak to peak values. I have assumed here, that the `NegVol` values are actually negative voltages.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It works like a treat!

Comment: In need for a bit more wisdom! If I have an uneven numbers of peaks, I get the error `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`. It might happen that there is one less negative peak than the positives and vice versa. How can I fix this?

Comment: @user3406207 Probably, `find` does not actually find anything and thus returns an empty array. You could check for that with `if(~isempty(neg_index))` and create the `PeakPeakFalling` dynamically and add a peak to peak distance only if `find` returned something.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the problem! Thanks a million!